# How to format the transcript of a telephonic conversation for email?

Tags: creative-writing, business-writing, email

What is the usual and customary way to write an e-mail to my lead for the telephonic conversation that I had with client or consultant? I need a formal format for the minutes of a conversation that I had over call for purpose of record.

Comment: Do you mean "write up a transcript of the conversation"?

Comment: yes, the minutes of conversation that i had over call for purpose of record.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Why can't you write up the minutes and email the document? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just need a formal format for the mail.

Comment: What sort of format do you usually use when emailing your lead? Can't you just use that and include the details of the conversation?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for the formatting for the transcript you're trying to write of a phone conversation you had.  Is this a legal type transcript?  If so, then you'll find a lot of examples if you google, "Legal Transcript Format Examples."  You might also google, "Telephone Transcript."  Again, you'll find lots of examples.  A little research might help.

Comment: I'm unclear why you're asking this question. Is there a reason you can't just use one of the templates you can find on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write an email to follow up and phone conversation, here are some points you might want to include: express appreciation for the person's time in talking with you; list key topics discussed; summarize agreements reached; identify next steps to take and dates for completion; include your contact details.

Comment: There points are really helpful to me.

Comment: Happy to help.  Good luck!